# Is it possible to use lupdate (QtLinguist) in a java project?

Tags: java, qt, internationalization, qt-jambi

I need to do the internationalization of an existing Java project. I am already using Qt Linguist in a C++ project using Qt and I would like (and have) to keep the same process for my Java project, instead of using the java RessourceBundles.

The help of lupdate specifies that it is possible to use Java files as input, but I have no idea of how to do this. Is it even possible ? Or is this purpose dead with Qt Jambi ?

Thanks,

Roland

Answer (score 0):

Since the *Jambi* project is discontinued, you will probably not be able to use a current version of Qt Linguist with any Java project. Most features rely heavily on C++ specific language features (e.g. signatures of the translation methods, macros), so without a specific Java port it looks pretty bleak.

**TLDR:** Most likely: no. You will have use something different for translation (or write in C++ :) ).

Comment: In Qt 5.6.0, lupdate still parses Java files by default for the ts strings. This enabled me to generate my ts files for Java. of course on the top of that I had to write a specific module to parse and apply the translated ts files at runtime. That's how I solved this issue.

Comment: That answers your own question :) For people who have the same problem, it might be cool if you could open-source your parsing code (if you haven't already).